# Is it valid to move and use unique pointer in single statement?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am getting segmentation fault on below line of my code with stacktrace as stated below. `self` is a `unique_ptr` here.

```
self->socket.async_send_to(self->frame->get_asio_buffer(), self->client_endpoint,
                           std::bind(&download_server::receiver, std::move(self), std::placeholders::_1, 
                           std::placeholders::_2));
```

Stacktrace. #3 is code line mentioned above

```
==1652==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000090 (pc 0x55e763e1bdc9 bp 0x7ffc2242d380 sp 0x7ffc2242d370 T0)
==1652==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==1652==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x55e763e1bdc9 in std::__shared_ptr<tftp::frame, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::get() const /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1325
    #1 0x55e763e1a9d5 in std::__shared_ptr_access<tftp::frame, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2, false, false>::_M_get() const /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1024
    #2 0x55e763e1948d in std::__shared_ptr_access<tftp::frame, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2, false, false>::operator->() const /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1018
    #3 0x55e763e0d665 in tftp::download_server::sender(std::unique_ptr<tftp::download_server, std::default_delete<tftp::download_server> >&, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) ../src/tftp_server.cpp:50
    #4 0x55e763e0cf56 in tftp::download_server::serve(boost::asio::io_context&, std::shared_ptr<tftp::frame const> const&, boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::udp> const&) ../src/tftp_server.cpp:27
    #5 0x55e763e0da65 in spin_tftp_server(boost::asio::io_context&, std::shared_ptr<tftp::frame const> const&, boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::udp> const&) ../src/tftp_server.cpp:97
    #6 0x55e763e0e3f5 in tftp::distributor::perform_distribution_cb(boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long const&) ../src/tftp_server.cpp:142
    #7 0x55e763e273fe in void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (tftp::distributor::*&)(boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long const&), std::shared_ptr<tftp::distributor>&, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long const&>(std::__invoke_memfun_deref, void (tftp::distributor::*&)(boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long const&), std::shared_ptr<tftp::distributor>&, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long const&) /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/invoke.h:73
```

In the above code `self` is used and moved in a single statement. Is it a valid ? If yes then what is the sequence of usage of `self` ?

Code on top of trace file(file /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h)

```
1322       /// Return the stored pointer.
1323       element_type*
1324       get() const noexcept
1325       { return _M_ptr; }
1326
```

As per comment here on line 1322 it seems like above usage is invalid. At runtime it's failing to find data pointed by unique pointer. Is this reading correct ?

However if above hypothesis is correct then below sample code should also crash. Here `self->t.async_wait` does similar thing(moving and using in same statement) however this worked without any trouble.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

class looper {
public:
  static void create(boost::asio::io_context &io){
    std::unique_ptr<looper> self = std::make_unique<looper>(io);
    start(self, boost::system::error_code());
  }

  static void start(std::unique_ptr<looper> &self, const boost::system::error_code e){
    std::cout << "Round :" << self->count << std::endl;
    if(self->count-- == 0){
      return;
    }
    self->t.expires_after(boost::asio::chrono::seconds(1));
    self->t.async_wait(std::bind(&looper::start, std::move(self), std::placeholders::_1));
  }

  looper(boost::asio::io_context &io) : t(io) {
    std::cout << "Construction" << std::endl;
  }

  ~looper() {
    std::cout << "Destruction" << std::endl;
  }
  boost::asio::steady_timer t;
  uint32_t count = 3;
};

void f(boost::asio::io_context &io){
  looper::create(io);
}

int main() {
  boost::asio::io_context io;
  f(io);
  io.run();
  return 0;
}
```

Output of sample program

```
[root@archlinux cpp]# g++ unique_async.cpp  -lpthread -fsanitize=address -Wpedantic
[root@archlinux cpp]# ./a.out
Construction
Round :3
Round :2
Round :1
Round :0
Destruction
[root@archlinux cpp]#
```

If `std::move` is problem then why first case crashes but sample programs runs without any problem.

Comment: You have UB (undefined behaviour). The order of the evaluation of function's parameters is unspecified. Thus, `self->socket.async_send_to(self->frame->get_asio_buffer(), ...` and `std::move(self)` is UB.

Comment: By UB you mean "undefined behavior" ?

Comment: The problem is the nested call to `bind`, which empties `self` before it is accessed by the other arguments. The `move(self)` itself is not problematic; for example, `self->foo(self->bar, move(self))` would be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `move(self)` itself is not problematic. It is the combination of a nested call to `bind` and other arguments that access `self`. The call to `bind` empties `self` before it is accessed by the other arguments.

You have two show-cases:

```
// bad
self->socket.async_send_to(self->frame->get_asio_buffer(),
                           self->client_endpoint,
                           bind(&download_server::receiver, move(self), _1, _2));
// good
self->t.async_wait(bind(&looper::start, move(self), _1));
```

Before, C++17, both cases had undefined behavior because the arguments were evaluated in an unspecified order and are also unsequenced. This includes the object expression before the function call (before `(`).

Starting with C++17, argument expressions are indeterminately sequenced, but the object expression is sequenced before the other arguments. The consequences are:

- In the bad case, `bind` can be invoked before the other arguments, and that would clear `self`, leading a null pointer access when the other arguments are evaluated.
- In the good case, however, the object expression is invoked first while `self` is still valid, and following that `bind` is invoked, which clears `self`; but since there are no other arguments to evaluate, the call is fine.